# 32bit Control Panel Items are missing after logon

Tags: windows-7

I am having an issue with my Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit.  Frequently when I login I cannot open Outlook because it states that the offline file is missing.  Now, I know it isn't because I look in the folder.  Usually I just logoff and log back on.

Well recently I read online that it may be my mail profile. So I went to the Control Panel, opened the Mail (32 bit) app and checked all of my settings.  I saved and then opened Outlook just fine.

Then it happened again with the "missing" offline file.  So I head back to the Control Panel to find that the Mail (32 bit) is not there.  Then I notice that none of the 32-bit control panel items are there.  Strange.

So I logoff and login again.  This time the 32-bit items are there and Outlook opens just fine without me touching the Mail control panel item.  This is getting really annoying and unproductive dealing with this almost daily.

I have checked the Event logs and nothing stands out.  The only issues I have there are with the Kaspersky antivirus my company runs.

Any thoughts on what may be causing this?

Comment: Sounds like your windows installation is corrupt.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was starting to think along those lines also but wanted to check on here first.